# Store can not dynamic register a dynamic imported module

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I want to implement a feature that can register and unregister some modules when components created/destroyed, and my test like this:

```js
// ../store/DMRTest.ts
const DMRTest = {
    state: { name: 'DMR test ' },
    mutations: {
        getName(state) {
            state.name += state.name;
        }
    },
    actions: {},
    getters: { NN(state) { return state.name; } },
};

export default DMRTest;

// App.vue
  import DMRTest from '../store/DMRTest.ts';
  // ...
  async created() {
      // Not works!
      this.$store.registerModule('DMRTest', await import('../store/DMRTest.ts'));
      // Works
      this.$store.registerModule('DMRTest', DMRTest);
      console.log(this.$store);
      console.log(this.$store.state);
  }
```

When I import the module statically, it will be registered correctly:

[image: correct]

But when I use `import` function, the store registered the module like this:

[image: have problem]

How could I import the module dynamically?

Comment: try logging the result of the await. You may need to register the `default` property of the promise result.

Comment: @EricGuan Yes! You are right! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I should append the `default` after the dynamic imported, question closed

Answer (score 0):

Just so it is written with an example:

```
const store = new createStore(rootStoreModule);
const modules = ['moduleA', 'moduleB']
for(const module of modules) {
    import(`./components/${ module.toLowerCase() }/store.js`)
    .then( (obj) => { store.registerModule(module, obj.default); } )
}
```